# Using OpenLayers and GeoJSON?

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

Recently I started learning Openlayers 2x and I've been struggling for a while now with a GeoJSON and it's projections.

So, here is the deal;

I successfully added wms layers from ( http://geoportal.dgu.hr/podaci-i-servisi/svi-servisi-i-aplikacije/ ) with a projection HTRS96/TM (EPSG:3765) and then when I try to add vector layer it doesn't render it. Vector layer was created using QGIS software with a projection code:

`"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3765" }`

Here is the  OpenLayers code:

```
var map;

function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {
        projection: 'EPSG:3765',
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(426906.034398, 5101783.64664,
        468058.881494, 5123976.6968),
        numZoomLevels:15,
        maxResolution: 'auto',
        units: 'm'              
    });
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        'DOF 1:5000',
        'http://geoportal.dgu.hr/wms?layers=DOF',
        {}
    );

    var wms2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        'TK 1:25 000',
        'http://geoportal.dgu.hr/wms?layers=TK25',
        {}
    );

        var wms3 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        'HOK',
        'http://geoportal.dgu.hr/wms?layers=HOK',
        {}
    );

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}));
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());


    var KZZ = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KZZ", {
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "KZZ_JLS.json",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    strategies: [
        new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()
    ]
});

    map.addLayers([wms,wms2,wms3,KZZ]);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}
```

And here is GeoJSON layer (fragment of it, whole file can be downloaded from this link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/126827789/KZZ_JLS.json):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3765" } },                                                                         
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "POVRINA": 27.027842695, "NAZIV": "Stubièke         Toplice" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 457191.01612696185, 5094147.6274271049 ], [ 457199.98992743361, 5094130.2420611409 ], [ 457231.34151837695, 5094112.0906051407 ], [ 457283.71295271069, 5094094.2316290718 ], [ 457310.09355065826,....
```

How can I render GeoJSON and add it to this file?

This problematic openlayers map can be viewed here htt()p://interaktiva.pregrada.hr/nc/--> to low reputation to add 2nd link on my post, pls remove **()**

Comment: From a quick glance I would say it is projection related, you wms is in 4326 (lat/lon) and your JSON in projected meters, 3765. This is a fairly common issue and can be dealt with by setting a map and display projection and using transform on your JSON to convert it. I am afraid I don't have time to give you a working example, but if you search for transform coordinates in OpenLayers you should find something.

Comment: Hmm, it says in WMS specification that original projection is EPSG:3765, (i'm referring to WMS that's in the posted map) same as JSON. Nevertheless, thank you for your kindness and time, I ll look into transforming coordinates and try to figure it out from there.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my Serbo-Croat is a bit rusty :-) If they are the same projection, then there is a different problem.

Comment: No problem :) I' ll cruise google for solution, maybe I'll find something useful. Thank you once again!

Comment: If  you put up a working example in jsfiddle, it might help also.

Comment: I took a look to your link, and it seems you added you geojson layer correctly right?

Comment: I believe that I did. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Neven Did you define EPSG:3765 with PROJ4? I can see, it is a Croatian projection, which isn't coded in the OL2 library. You have to define it with PROJ4js. If you did so, you can also try to include a `projection` parameter to your vector layer.

Comment: @Gabor Farkas. I did include PROJ4. When I tested file I tried several options one of which was including projection parameter to vector layer and it didn't work. I must say that I'm pretty confused about possible solutions. Help :)

Comment: @Neven I have noticed one problem with your GeoJSON. It has 3 coordinates, but OL2 can only process two. You can fix it with modifying the `format` parameter: `format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({ignoreExtraDims: true})`. Now it loads the features in the layer, but it still doesn't render. Maybe you have to generalize the polygons. If I'll have more time, I'll take a look at it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final answer is: your vector data is out of range. There were two problems with your map.

The first was, that your dataset contains three coordinate for every point, while OpenLayers 2 can only handle two. To fix this, you have to include an `ignoreExtraDims` parameter to your `format` object:

```
format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
    ignoreExtraDims: true
})
```

The second problem is, that your data is in the wrong place. Your WMS layers range roughly from 430.000 m to 480.000 m in X axis, and from 5.100.000 m to 5.130.000 m in Y axis. Your data, however ranges from 5.546.000 m to 5.597.000 m in X axis, while the Y range is correct. You have to shift your data to the correct place prior to visualizing.

Comment: Thx, I ll look into that as soon as possible. To be fair, I do have one question regarding third coordinate point. I looked it up at my GeoJSON file and I see only two coordinate **457191.01612696185, 5094147.6274271049** for every point

Comment: You have to look a little bit closer, it is `5573986.9868397331, 5093902.9130302276, 0.0`.

Comment: Thx, I've missed it. Good job!

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid that I don't understand the second problem. When I add layers in QGIS (vector and wms) they overlap perfectly (added layers have same EPSG code 3765) and when I convert from .shp to .geojson and try to add that same vector layer it doesn't render it.

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with QGIS's GeoJSON export? Try to compare the coordinates in the shapefile and in the GeoJSON. I assume this, because you had a `457191.01612696185` coordinate in X axis, while I have only 6 digit coordinates there scaling from 5.500.000.

Comment: To put it mildly, I'm confused. If u want, you can download shapefile from this link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/126827789/KZZ_JLS.7z

Comment: I see. There is something wrong with the GeoJSON export. I could manage to export it in KML properly. You can try to export it in other OL2 capable format, or convert it to GeoJSON with another software than ogr2ogr.

Comment: It works now, don't know how but it works. Apparently problem was in     `ignoreExtraDims: true` and size of geoJSON file, it needed some time to render it! Thank you guys!